# How can I only print the elements in 2D array that have a certain char?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, char

I'm trying to only print the ones in row 0 that have an M. I have tried using two for loops and it just keeps either printing all of them twice or printing all of them once. Never can i just get the MD MA ME etc.

```
String [][] geo = {{"MD","NY","NJ","MA","ME","CA","MI","OR",},
            {"Detroit","Newark","Boston","Seattle"}};

        for (int j = 0; j < geo[0].length; j++)
        {
            if (geo[0][j].charAt(0) == 'M');
            System.out.println(geo[0][j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your if statement needs to have a block after it instead of a newline.
            `if (geo[0][j].charAt(0) == 'M')
            {
                System.out.println(geo[0][j]);
            }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semi-colon after the `if` statement so the `System.out.println` statement is not actually inside it. Without the semi-colon it would work, but you should get in the habit of using braces to wrap the lines inside your `if` statement, even if there's only one.

Removed semi-colon, it works, but it's prone to error if you add another statement to your `if`

```
String [][] geo = {{"MD","NY","NJ","MA","ME","CA","MI","OR",},
        {"Detroit","Newark","Boston","Seattle"}};

    for (int j = 0; j < geo[0].length; j++)
    {
        if (geo[0][j].charAt(0) == 'M')
            System.out.println(geo[0][j]);
    }
}
```

This is unambiguous and clear:

```
String [][] geo = {{"MD","NY","NJ","MA","ME","CA","MI","OR",},
        {"Detroit","Newark","Boston","Seattle"}};

    for (int j = 0; j < geo[0].length; j++)
    {
        if (geo[0][j].charAt(0) == 'M') {
            System.out.println(geo[0][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well explained @Matt

Answer (score 0):

The if block code is null since you have a semi-colon at the end of it. Try removing it or using brackets to enclose the print statement.

```
if (geo[0][j].charAt(0) == 'M')
{
        System.out.println(geo[0][j])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I observed the code, and the issue seemed to be with the if statement... here's the working code:

```
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
             {
    String [][] geo = {{"MD","NY","NJ","MA","ME","CA","MI","OR",},
           {"Detroit","Newark","Boston","Seattle"}};

        for (int j = 0; j < geo[0].length; j++)
    {
        if (geo[0][j].charAt(0) == 'M'){
        System.out.println(geo[0][j]);
}
    }
}
```